# how to add border to a text in textview android

Tags: android, border, textview

In Android, how can you add a border around a text? I want a border around the text in TextView not *around* the TextView.Is there any way to do it in? If so, please point me to the proper steps needed to do..

Answer (score 32):

Try this..

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textColor="#f8f36a"
    android:textSize="65sp"
    android:shadowColor="#ff0000" 
    android:shadowRadius="2"/>
```

and the result is

[image: result]

You can create custom border for text like this..[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/m5/MagicTextView).

[image]

Comment: I used MagicTextView in my project. In Android 4.4 (API 19) I encountered a problem: my application crashes somewhere in a C-library. It happens only in Android 4.4. And my application works well, if I use TextView instead of MagicTextView.

Answer (score 19):

You can create style for this..

Here is [sample style](http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/10/shadow-effect-glow-effect-on-textview.html) for borderline on text..

**Style.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <style name="shadoweffect">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">3</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Apply style on your TextView

```
 <TextView
      style="@style/shadoweffect"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="your_text" />
```

Comment: Excellent Solution, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Android does not have such feature originally. A few months ago, I had to develop a similar feature, and I used some trick. In that case I used the `shadow` attribute. In your case on `TextView.onDraw()` call `super()` two times. Set the typeface to bold and set the color to border color and call one time, and set normal and call second time. That will work.

Comment: **Android does not have such feature originally.** are you sure? I think your process is long.

Answer (score -4):

You can use any TextEditors to create a border for ur text and you can add to the code

Comment: I think the OP was looking for a solution by setting values in the XML?