# Xml: stroke, border, outline text inside button

Tags: android, xml, border, stroke, outline

I want to add a white stroke to black text inside a button. I can figure out to do this with regular textview but not when it comes to a button.

Thi is regarding Xml android studio btw.

activity_main.xml:

```
   <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/login_button_style"
    android:text="Log Ind"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextPass"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextPass"
    android:clickable="true" /><![CDATA[
/>
```

login_button_style.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#d7d7d7"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
<stroke android:color="#d10f0f" android:width="3dp" />

<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="shadoweffect">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">25sp</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowDy">0</item>
        <item name="android:shadowRadius">3</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

[image]

can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: post your code & image about what you exactly want and what happening .

Comment: there is no image. We are talking about a regular button in Android Studio that I want to add a border to the text inside it.

Comment: do you want button border or only the text border?

Comment: actually both Kumar. But i have already fixed the button border myself. it is the text border that is causing me trouble

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22299305/624069

Comment: Niranj that is for textview and not for a button.

Comment: you can also apply background to textview so it will look like button and you can also apply this style on button too.

Comment: I have just tried applying this to a button. It doesn't work.

Comment: will edit with code in a minut

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer to a similar question on how to make a border. He creates a new file that is a shape of just that color then stores it as a drawable to be used as the background image 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690416/android-border-for-button

Just change the color to white and there you go

EDIT:

Actually seeing now. You want the letters to be *outlined* in white.

So my best guess would be to draw the entire image with the text and border up in Photoshop/Sketch. And then save *that* as a drawable. To set for your buttons background. Make sure to set the buttons text to just quotes since you will already have the text in the Photoshop mockup

```
android:text = ""
```